# After implemented state machine for my player, i can't use variables of the state manager inside state scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I've refactored my player controller and I've implemented a hierarchical state machine.

I want to maintain some variables inside the state manager because they are re-used a lot in my code (e.g. player direction based on input). The problem is: when I'm trying to use the variables, stored in the state manager, inside each different state script, after hitting play they update themselves only in the state manager, instead, the references are equal to their default values.

Below there is an example of some logic behind my implementation (To let them readable, I'm not copying all of their variables and methods), if needed I'll append a link with all the files

**Player base state. This defines common logic between states**

```cs
public abstract class PlayerBaseState
{

    protected PlayerStateMachine _context;

    protected PlayerStateFactory _factory;
    protected PlayerBaseState _currentSuperState;
    protected PlayerBaseState _currentSubState;

    public PlayerBaseState(PlayerStateMachine context, PlayerStateFactory factory)
    {
        _context = context;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public abstract void EnterState();

    public abstract void UpdateState();

    public abstract void ExitState();
    public abstract void CheckSwitchStates();

    public abstract void InitialSubState();

    public void UpdateStates()
    {
        UpdateState();

        if (_currentSubState != null)
            _currentSubState.UpdateStates();
    }


    protected void SetSuperState(PlayerBaseState newSuperState)
    {
        _currentSuperState = newSuperState;
    }

    protected void SetSubState(PlayerBaseState newSubState)
    {
        _currentSubState = newSubState;
        newSubState.SetSuperState(this);
    }

    protected void SwitchStates(PlayerBaseState newState)
    {
        ExitState();

        newState.EnterState();

        _context.currentState = newState;
    }


}
```

**Player grounding state**

```cs
public class PlayerGroundingState : PlayerBaseState
{

    public PlayerGroundingState(PlayerStateMachine context, PlayerStateFactory factory)
     : base(context, factory)
    {
        InitialSubState();
    }

    public override void EnterState()
    {
        _context.rb.drag = _context.groundDrag;
    }

    public override void UpdateState()
    {
        Debug.Log("Ground state: " + _context.direction);
        GroundMovement();

        CheckSwitchStates();
    }
   

    /// <summary>
    /// Move the player to the horizontal plane
    /// </summary>
    private void GroundMovement()
    {

        if (_context.direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            _context.rb.AddForce(_context.direction * _context.walkingSpeed * _context.movementMultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

**Player state manager**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// State field
    /// </summary>
    public PlayerBaseState currentState;
    public PlayerBaseState subCurrentState { get; set; }
    public PlayerStateFactory playerStateFactory { get; set; }


    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] public Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] public Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] public PlayerAnimator playerAnimator;

    [Header("Ground check fields")]
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask groundMask;


    [Header("Walk fields")]
    public float walkingSpeed;

    [Header("Dash fields")]
    public float dashForce;
    public float dashCooldown;

    [Tooltip("Moltiplicatore per velocità di movimento")]
    public float movementMultiplier;
    public float airMultiplier = .5f;

    [Tooltip("Drag attributes for different situations")]
    public float groundDrag, airDrag;

    [Header("Multiple jumps variables")]
    public float jumpForce;
    public int jumpCounter;
    public int maxJumpCounter { get; set; }
    public string jumpButton = "Jump";

    private float _horizontal;
    private float _vertical;
    private Vector3 _direction;
    private bool _canDash;
    private bool _freeze;
    private bool _isGrounded;

    public float horizontal { get { return _horizontal; } set { _horizontal = value;  } }
    public float vertical { get { return _vertical; } set { _vertical= value; } }
    public Vector3 direction { get { return _direction; } set { _direction = value; } }
    public bool canDash { get { return _canDash; } set { _canDash = value; } }
    public bool freeze { get { return _freeze; } set { _freeze = value; } }
    public bool isGrounded { get { return _isGrounded; } set { _isGrounded = value; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<PlayerAnimator>();

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        playerStateFactory = new PlayerStateFactory(this);
        currentState = playerStateFactory.Grounded();
        currentState.EnterState();

        Debug.Log(currentState.ToString());
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        currentState.UpdateStates();
        
        //Controlla se il player è a terra
        _isGrounded = IsGrounded();

        //Ricava il vettore di movimento
        GetDirectionVector();
        DashHandler(); //Permette di fare dash in ogni statox

        Debug.Log(direction + "; " + isGrounded);

    }

    public void GetDirectionVector()
    {
        _horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        _vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        _direction = transform.forward * _vertical + transform.right * _horizontal;

    }


    public bool IsGrounded() => Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, groundMask);




}
```

**For context, PlayerStateFactory instantiates every player state based on player conditions**

```cs
public class PlayerStateFactory
{
    PlayerStateMachine _context;

    public PlayerStateFactory(PlayerStateMachine context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public PlayerBaseState Idle()
    {
        return new PlayerIdleState(_context, this);
    }
    public PlayerBaseState Walking()
    {
        return new PlayerWalkingState(_context, this);
    }
    public PlayerBaseState Jumping()
    {
        return new PlayerJumpState(_context, this);
    }
    public PlayerBaseState Grounded()
    {
        return new PlayerGroundingState(_context, this);
    }

    public PlayerBaseState InAir()
    {
        return new PlayerInAirState(_context, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I don't know that i need to write

```
using UnityEngine
```

inside all the class of unity.